# Excel Data Compare in Pandas with 3 ORs (Boolean)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm having issues with Pandas and a Conditional comparing.
I have Excel A with a Country, City, State and ZipCode. Excel B has a list of City, State, Zip Code.
The idea is to check if in my Excel A each Row with Country Blank has a City, State and Zip combination that matches the row in B with the proper combination.

When I ran it I got partial results. It looks like is working partially.

```
# PRE- Check 4: Leer Archivo con US ZipCode.
print('leyendo archivo con ZipCode data...')
df = pd.read_excel(zpath,dtype={"Zip Code":str})
valid_zipcode = np.array(df["Zip Code"])
valid_city = np.array(df["Official USPS city name"].str.upper())
valid_state = np.array(df["Official USPS State Code"].str.upper())
print('Data de ZipCode en memoria...')

# Check 4: Validar City/State/ZipCode.
print("Performing check4...")
check4 = lambda t,u,v,w: pd.isna(t) and (u not in valid_city and v not in valid_state and w not in valid_zipcode)
vcheck4 = np.vectorize(check4)
result4 = vcheck4(dataf.loc[:, "CountryName"], dataf.loc[:, "City"],dataf.loc[:, "State"],dataf.loc[:, "PostalCode"])
test_bool = result4
failed_reason = update_failed_reason(failed_reason, vadd_failnum(result4, "4, "))
print('Chequeo de Zip/City/State completado..........')
```

So in  my test I have 2 rows. One with correct data and the other with the good city and zipcode but wrong state, and the script is giving to both FALSE. Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to perform a 'left' [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) (left outer join in SQL) with your dataframes along with an indicator. Assuming that your values are already formatted correctly (i.e. you've aleady applied `str.upper`) the merge is as simple as

```
merged = pd.merge(df, dataf,
                 left_on=['Official USPS city name', 'Official USPS State Code', 'Zip Code'],
                 right_on=['City', 'State', 'PostalCode'],
                 how='left', indicator=True)
```

`indicator=True` means that the resulting dataframe will contain a new column `_merge` which will have a value `'both'` if the merge keys were present in both dataframes (i.e. there was a corresponding row in `dataf`), or `left_only'` if the merge keys only originated from `df`.

Checking whether all rows in `df` have corresponding (city, state, zipcode) in `dataf` then comes down to using the following

```
not (merged._merge == 'left_only').any()
```